# Pulling Times and value in the 4th Column in a text file

Tags: c#, forms, streamreader, readfile

I am trying to develop a program that reads HRM files. The textfile looks like this:

```
[IntTimes]
00:09:59.0  117 91  127 153
0   0   0   124 41  309
0   0   0   0   0
0   2181    68  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:10:00.0  115 91  127 153
0   0   0   119 0   309
0   0   0   0   0
33554432    2184    0   0   0   0
500 0   0   0   0   0
00:20:10.0  173 109 161 177
0   0   0   112 62  307
0   0   0   0   0
0   3461    22  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:25:02.0  119 111 126 172
0   0   0   190 54  308
0   0   0   0   0
0   764 133 0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:35:16.0  174 119 167 179
0   0   0   121 52  309
0   0   0   0   0
0   3500    70  0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:50:00.0  134 109 153 179     
0   0   0   178 0   310
0   0   0   0   0
33554432    10840   0   0   0   0
500 0   0   0   0   0
01:00:00.0  150 112 139 175
0   0   0   66  0   312
0   0   0   0   0
33554432    1741    0   0   0   0
500 0   0   0   0   0
01:06:18.9  108 105 139 177
0   0   0   64  123 313
0   0   0   0   0
0   5668    0   80  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I am wanting to collect all of the times and store them in a list or array that I will then use to plot onto ZedGraph. I also need to collect the 4th digit along on the same line as each time.

For example the first line underneath `[IntTimes]` I want to collect '`00:09:59.0`', store it, then collect `127` and store it. Same with the row for `00:10:00.0` and so on until there aren't times left.

I have developed part of the code to look for the values between the square brackets, as below, using a regex of `@"\[(.*?)\]"`:

```
  if (squareBrackets.Match(line).Success)
        {
            titles.Add(line);
            if (textAfterTitles.Match(line).Success)
            {
                textaftertitles.Add(line);

            }
        }
```

Sounds a bit long winded but I didn't really know what to search to achieve this so thought this is the best place.

Thanks

Comment: You will have to read each line,split it into an string array and then extract the 0th index and 3rd index from the array.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read each line,split it into a string array and then extract the 0th index and 3rd index from the array.

```
 NameValueCollection kv = new NameValueCollection();// Choose your data structure. name value collection allows duplicates.
 using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader("your_file_path"))
 {
        while ((sLine = oReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
             if(!sLine.Contains("[IntTimes]") && !sLine.Contains("[IntNotes]"))
            {
                 string[] sLineItems = sLine.Split('\t');// Assuming the file is tab delimited.
                 kv.Add(sLineItems[0],sLineItems[3]);
                 Console.WriteLine(sLineItems[0],sLineItems[3]);
            } 
        }
 }
 foreach(string key in kv.AllKeys)
        Console.WriteLine(key,kv[key]);
```

Comment: Thankyou - How could I code into it to only read the lines after [IntTimes] as I haven't shown the whole text file that's a snippet. Also at the end of that section is [IntNotes] so I'd need it between those two. How could I do this? Thankyou

Comment: Add check to ignore lines that contain [IntTimes] and [IntNotes].I've edited the code to include the check for those two strings in the line.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CSV tool to parse the file? I've used the [CSV Helper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) on various text files myself and it can tackle lots of different formats. There's a lot of configurations you can set to adjust the parsing to your needs.

It's also available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/).